# Unable to list element from array list in Playwright

Tags: javascript, playwright

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYdgj.png)I need to sum up all the column content displayed in UI table. To get the elements of column used below syntax:

```
async findele() {
  let result =  await this.igetListOfElements("(//tr[contains(@class,'dxgvDataRow_DaimlerThemev3')])//td[4]");

  console.log(result);
}
```

The terminal elements are not listed and printed as `[]`, ie. empty.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7DqS.png)

Comment: It's unclear how to help here without the site and a [mcve]. Thanks.

Comment: added the relevant site image

Comment: Thanks, but it's hard to scrape an image, sorry. I'd have to re-type in the HTML, probably make a million mistakes and incorrect assumptions about how the site works. It'd be a lot of work for me and probably wouldn't even fix your problem. I'd like to have code I can run and play with so I can verify it works.

Answer (score 1):

That's how I would capture an column data from table in an array:

(row and column info I used are arbitrary, pls change it per your scenario)

Once I have data in an array , I can do all sorts of operations like sum.

```
const textsFrom4thColumn = [];    
const rowCount = await page.locator('Table-Locator').locator('tr').count();

for (let i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
  textsFrom4thColumn.push(Number(await page.locator('Table-Locator').locator('tr').nth(i).locator('td').nth(3).innerText()))
}
```

Once I have the desired data in an array, I can do the sum as below using JavaScript [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function:

```
const result = textsFrom4thColumn.reduce((sum, num) => sum + num, 0);
console.log(result);
```